# HDMI Capture Card MacroSilicon MS2109: MIssing Audio Device on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: drivers, sound, alsa, hdmi

I have a HDMI-USB-Grabber MacroSilicon MS2109 that worked under Ubuntu 20.04 without problems. I could stream the HDMI-Input using this command line:

```
ffmpeg -f v4l2 -input_format mjpeg -framerate 25 -video_size 1280x720 -i /dev/video0 -f alsa -i iec958:CARD=MS2109,DEV=0 -c:v libx264 -b:v 1600k -preset fast -x264opts keyint=50 -g 25 -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:a aac -b:a 128k -f rtp_mpegts rtp://239.0.0.2:5001?ttl=2
```

This works for video only. The Problem is the Audio Device. This are all audio devices 'arecord -L' founds:

```
hw:CARD=MS2109,DEV=0
    MS2109, USB Audio
    Direct hardware device without any conversions
plughw:CARD=MS2109,DEV=0
    MS2109, USB Audio
    Hardware device with all software conversions
sysdefault:CARD=MS2109
    MS2109, USB Audio
    Default Audio Device
front:CARD=MS2109,DEV=0
    MS2109, USB Audio
    Front output / input
dsnoop:CARD=MS2109,DEV=0
    MS2109, USB Audio
    Direct sample snooping device
usbstream:CARD=MS2109
    MS2109
    USB Stream Output
```

As you can see the Device "iec958:CARD=MS2109,DEV=0" is missing. I tried all Devices in the List without success. I also tried the output of "arecord -l" (i.e. -f hw:2 or -f hw:2,0). Nothing works.

Is there a driver module missing or something?

Comment: I found that i can record audio with "arecord -d 25 -f cd test1.wav".